# Python Regex pattern matching throws error, with hyphen

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a pattern from a string using the regex -

```
\"([a-zA-Z0-9/-_\"]+)\""

command = '"custom-ts-name": "asdf-somenum"'
search_string = "\"custom-ts-name\": \"([a-zA-Z0-9/-_\"]+)\""
pattern = re.compile(search_string)
ts_name = pattern.findall(command)[0]
```

It works most of the time, except when the result string, `asdf-somenum` contains a hypen in it.

I have added hyphen between square brackets inside the regex - `\"([a-zA-Z0-9/-_\"]+)\""`, to address this but not sure, why it crashes still?

Comment: Escape the hyphen or use at last/first position in character class: `\"([a-zA-Z0-9/_\"-]+)\"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-` inside character sets has the special meaning of *from-to*. For example, the `a-z` you have used means all lowcase letters. You can put the dash in either first/last position or escape it:

```
\"([a-zA-Z0-9/_\"-]+)\""
```